# Earth Engine import record, why?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

When I paste the following on EE online code editor then if offers me the option to convert to an import record.

```
var l8sr = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
var roi = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([-123.1231231231234, 38.1231231231234]);
```

One disadvantage I found on converting it to import record is that quick copy (Crtl+C) of code do not get those imports.

Instead, I can Ctrl+C them if I leave them as normal code.

And I do not actually know the advantage of having them as imported records. May I ask what's the advantage?

Comment: You can easily drag around or slightly adapt geometries which are import record. It is always easier to share your code using the 'get link' button, which will use the import records.

Comment: I think the functionality of sharing the code works both ways, doesn't matter it using import records or not. Am I wrong?

Comment: You may copy the imports by clicking the list icon next to the imports section at the top of the imports ("Show generated code").

Comment: Another difference is on the visualisation. When it is imported, it automatically shows on the geometry imports menu on the top left, and that makes easier to change the visualisation parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For **running** a script, there is no advantage to using imports over code. And as you noticed, they do require extra steps to copy them.

The benefits of imports are when editing:

- For geometries: You can view and edit them graphically rather than by typing/pasting coordinates.
- For assets: You can open the asset info dialog to view documentation for public datasets or to edit the properties of your own assets.

It also may be easier to read a script by keeping the input data in the imports section and the calculation in the script section, but that is of course subjective.